# Create a chart using the records of certain type grouped by month, with a moving balance

Tags: crystal-reports, sage-crm

I am trying to create a chart (bar or line) in crystal from one table in my database (Sage CRM).

The records are as follows

```
CustomerId      Date            Invoice              Amount

1234           3/4/2013        Cust Invoice           3322.00   
1234           3/4/2013        Payment                2445.00  
1234           4/5/2013        A/c transaction         322.00  
1234           5/6/2013        interest                 32.00 
1234           6/6/2013        payment                 643.00
```

So I would like to have a report that meets the following criteria

1. Only records for the last 12 months  grouped in month
2. Only invoice types of payment, invoice and interest
3. A moving balance that calculates all the invoice amounts ie

(when displaying the  information for July 2012, the moving balance will be the total of all  invoices prior to this date.
Without this field I can create the chart no problem using select expert but I am not sure now what to do)

Should I use a cross tab? if so how will I do the selection to only show the invoices I want and the the date range I want?

Comment: Can you advise a little more about your setup? Do you have the ability to create stored procs on the database? If so I would recommend creating a stored procedure with some @ parameters. That way you can set your dates and invoice types when you refresh the report in crystal.

The moving balance can be easily created using a running total field... If you provide more information I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Hi Alec, The situation is that I am on 13 weeks workexperience, i started 3 weeks ago, and there is noone to mentor me, as there is no other it person (only the accountant who knows very little). I am installing wampserver so that i can create a stored procedure., is there anything else you wish to know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending almost a week on this problem, with a lot of help from an expert I have finally got a solution.

In order to create a amount that is the sum of all records for  a company, month and invoice type since the beginning of time, while only displaying records for the last year, I have created a SQL command

```
Select 
  //All of the fields for the report,
  movingBalance.Amount
from myInvoiceTable as mit
  <join to any other tables for the report>
  left join (
    select customerID, sum(amount) as Amount
    from myInvoiceTable
    where Record_Type in ('Payment', 'Invoice','Interest')
      and Date < {?Report Start Date}
    group by customerID) movingBalance
   on mit.customerID = movingBalance.customerID
where mit.RecordType in ('Payment', 'Invoice','Interest')
  and mit.Date >= {?Report Start Date}
  and mit.Date <= {?Report End Date}
```

There are a couple of tricks to using commands:

1. For performance reasons you generally want to include ALL of the data for the report in a single command.  Avoid joining multiple commands or joining one or more tables to a command.
2. Filter the data in the command, NOT in the Select Expert in the report.
3. Create any parameters in the Command Editor, not in the main report.  Parameters created in the report won't work in the Command Editor.

This has done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Create Date Parameters in the report to filter out the records at the time of fetching now when you run the report you have left with the data you need.

Now you can manuplate the data inside report using formula fields.

Accoding to me writing stored procedures is a bit hectic task as you can manuplate the data inside the report. I don't have any intentions to disrespect anyone opinions but frankly its my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In that case Rachsherry I would recommend the following.

For criteria parts 1 & 2 I think instead of using stored procs, it may be easier for you to use a formula.

For invoices right click the invoice field, then "Format Field" in the common tab next to the Suppress option there is a formula button, enter the following...

```
 IF {YourInvoiceField} IN ["Payment", "Invoice", "Interest] THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE
```

For your date requirement you need to use a selection formula... The code for that should look something like this

```
 {YourDateHere} > DateAdd ("yyyy", -1, CurrentDate) AND {YourDateHere} < CurrentDate
```

The above code basically looks at dates between the day the report is run, and exactly a year before.

For your moving balance, you should be able to achive that with the guide [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=isoPezxjvo8C&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=guide%20running%20total%20crystal&source=bl&ots=aJYkeoyKK9&sig=Oyitqnw7eGXP7Qpa1bM_uNlHIqI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_N34UdL5MMKw0QW_goGIAw&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=guide%20running%20total%20crystal&f=false)

**Edit - An alternative to this is to use parameter fields (Which I don't personally like) it just means having to input the parameters every time the report is refreshed, they are self explanatory but you can find a guide [here](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/92797a6e-467f-4876-8212-dd8a6c2e3dcc/?Parameter%20Field%20in%20Crystal%20Report)**

Comment: Hi Alec, I tried what you suggested above but it is not enough to restrict data for the chart, although it stops records displaying in the report, they still appear in the chart.